# Bash: copy file to the latest directory

Tags: bash, copy

I know that `cd -` goes back to the latest directory. Is there a similar shortcut for copying a file from the current directory to the latest directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work...:

```
cp file ~-
```

Comment: It works indeed, thanks. [This](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-tilde-expansion/#more-4794) explains why it works.